# Didn't declared variable still not getting any error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I was creating a validation form and by chance, I changed innerHTML of a div tag without declaring it at the top but that worked. I am not getting why that works without even declaring the error variable for div where I want to show the error

```
if(name == "") {
    // why it works although I didn't
    // declared nameError
    nameError.innerHTML = "Name is required";
}
```

Following is the codepen example

https://codepen.io/ihtisham-khan/pen/dyLVLeV

Comment: Do you have an element with that as an id?

Comment: This question has been marked as **duplicate** which is incorrect! The answer to your question is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Comment: Note that the properties of the `window` object do not necessarily need to be used after the `window.` but they can be used directly such as `window.addEventListener -> addEventListener ` or `window.name -> name`

Comment: @ArashJahanBakhshan The question is specifically about `nameError`. It says so in the question. The duplicate is correct as far as I can see.

Comment: @Carcigenicate oh no! My bad. I will be more careful next time :)